Two-stage Robust Shortest Path Problem - worst- case second-stage of an optimal solution
in the paper Improved Approximations for Two-stage Min-Cut and
Shortest Path Problems under Uncertainty chapter 4, they are using an algorithm to approximate the two-stage robust shortest path problem. In this algorithm they are using the worst- case second-stage of an optimal solution = $C$.
"Let $ E^*_f, E^{i*}_{s}, i = 1, \dots, k $ be an optimal solution for the robust shortest path problem, and let $ C $ be the worst-case second-stage cost, i.e.,
$C = \max_{i=1, \dots, k} \sigma_i \cdot c_f(E^*_{s_i}).$"
If you have an optimal solution, there are at most $k\cdot n$ choices to consider. I get where the $k\cdot n$ comes from but IF we have an optimal solution why even use the algorithm to get an approximate solution?
I'm not sure what they mean with "optimal solution" how do they derive it? If they already have a fixed optimal solution they are already done.
I have to be wrong somewhere but I don't know where.
